# Cant use angulars localStorage inside a class, how do i cache across sessions?

Tags: angular, caching

After the first GET-request, i cache a logo so i can return it from cache the next time without having to do the request again. If the logo gets updated, i delete the cache.

```
const BASE_URL = localStorage.getItem('resourceServer') + '/api/pictures/';

@Injectable()
export class PictureService {

  cachedLogo: Observable<Picture>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private notificationService: NotificationService,
              private handleService: HandleService) {
  }

  getLogo(): Observable<Picture> {
    if (!this.cachedLogo) {
      this.cachedLogo = this.http.get<Picture>(BASE_URL + 'logo', this.authService.setHeaders('application/json'))
        .pipe(
          publishReplay(1),
          refCount(),
          catchError(this.handleService.error.bind(this))
        );
    }
    return this.cachedLogo;
  }

  addPicture(picture: Picture): Observable<Picture> {
    this.cachedLogo = null;
    return this.http.post<Picture>(BASE_URL, picture, this.authService.setHeaders('application/json'))
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.handleService.success('Bild hochgeladen')),
        catchError(this.handleService.error.bind(this))
      );
  }

  updatePicture(picture: Picture): Observable<Picture> {
    this.cachedLogo = null;
    return this.http.put<Picture>(BASE_URL + picture.id, picture, this.authService.setHeaders('application/json'))
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.handleService.success('Bild bearbeitet')),
        catchError(this.handleService.error.bind(this))
      );
  }
}
```

The current approach obviously only works for a session. The cache doesnt persist across sessions. But thats what i would like to achieve. `localStorage` persists across sessions, but i cant use it inside the class. So how do i cache that logo across sessions?

Comment: What do you mean by across session ?

Comment: I mean that if i reload the page(enter another session) i should still be able to acces the logo from cache. But with my current approach, the cache disappears if i reload the page.

Comment: why you do not updatePicture() while user gets logged in? Compare if the same login then do not remove from storage else update it each time or a new session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually save your logo in the localstorage. That's why you always have retreive it, when you reload the page.

The LocalStorage service is accessible from inside the class with no problem. You could add a `setLogo` function that would add the logo inside the localstorage and set the property `this.cachedLogo`. Also, you need to retreive it when your class has loaded.

Here, we are implementing the  `onInit` interface to add the `ngOnInit` function that will run when the class is initializated. in this function, we retrieve the logo from the localstorage.

We also add the  `setLogo` function that will set our variable `cachedLogo` and define an item in the localStorage.

```
const BASE_URL = localStorage.getItem('resourceServer') + '/api/pictures/';

@Injectable()
export class PictureService implements OnInit {

  cachedLogo: Observable<Picture>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private notificationService: NotificationService,
              private handleService: HandleService) {
  }

  getLogo(): Observable<Picture> {
    if (!this.cachedLogo) {
      this.setLogo(this.http.get<Picture>(BASE_URL + 'logo', this.authService.setHeaders('application/json'))
        .pipe(
          publishReplay(1),
          refCount(),
          catchError(this.handleService.error.bind(this))
        ));
    }
    return this.cachedLogo;
  }

  /* ... */
  setLogo(logo: string): void {
      LocalStorage.setItem('logo', logo);
      this.cachedLogo = logo;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.cachedLogo = Localstorage.getItem('logo');
  }
}
```

**P.S.** Please note that this code is untested.

Comment: `getLogo()` returns and caches an observable. `localStorage` only allows me to save strings. I guess i could subscribe to the observable inside `setLogo(logo: Observable<Logo>)`, get that logo and save it as a Base64 string inside `localStorage` ?

Comment: that would make sense. @M.Dietz It is up to you to adjust this concept to fit your particular needs.